# How to create dict of dicts from list of dicts in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I want to convert list of dicts to dict of dicts by assigning a single key to all the values.
This is what i have:

> `[{'available_price': 5.99,
>     'category': 'Household'},
>    {'available_price': 5.49,
>     'category': 'Household'}]`

I want output to be like this:

> `{'single_key':[{'available_price': 5.99,
>     'category': 'Household'},
>    {'available_price': 5.49,
>     'category': 'Household'}]}`

Comment: `data  = [{'some': 'foo'}, {'bar': 'baz'}]; data = {'somekey': data}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you asked and what you gave as an example are 2 different things.

Here is The expected result for your example:

```
>>> simpleDic = { i : i*10 for i in range(5)}
>>> dicInList = [simpleDic]
>>> listInDic = {'single_key' : dicInList}
>>> print(simpleDic, dicInList, listInDic)
{0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}
[{0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}]
{'single_key': [{0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}]}
```

Here is The expected result for what you asked (a dictionary containing the original dictionary as a value for a given key 'single_key'):

```
>>> dicInDic = {'single_key' : simpleDic}
>>> dicInDic
{'single_key': {0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}}
```

Please make sure next time you look for the answer, I am sure you could find the answer alone. I hope it answers your question. Good Luck!